# Little bumps appearing where the staple went in for the 1/2" manufactured hardwood floor

Tags: flooring, engineered-flooring

I have little bumps appearing where the staple went in for the 1/2" manufactured hardwood floor.

[image]
Can't even tell they are there from the picture... Maybe I'm looking at it too closely.

These are my floors: http://www.johnsonhardwood.com/products/forevertuff-69/forevertuff-canadian-maple.html

They look great, but after a long day of install, I sat down and caught the light hitting the floor at an oblique angle and could see little bumps where the staples they recommended went in.  ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BKOD4AS/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BKOD4AS))

I tried hitting those spots with a rubber mallet and that has helped a great deal, but **what am I doing wrong in the first place**? My air compressor is set at the recommended 75PSI and I am aligning the flooring stapler correctly.

Comment: I feel like I should up-vote for using the word 'oblique.' I would bet the likely answer is not mechanical installation, but a thermal/humidity/differential expansion issue. Did the flooring spend enough time in the room where they were to be installed to sufficiently acclimate to conditions there?

Comment: What is the subfloor? Plywood? How thick? What's under the subfloor? Joists? Slab?

Comment: Plywood, not sure how thick but it's on joists.

Comment: To me the only way this could happen is if the staples aren't catching underneath (not long enough or wrong kind) or if they aren't in enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it turns out, the answer is I'm an idiot. I misread the guidelines and used the wrong gauge of staples.

As the result, I got this textbook description from the manufacturer:

> IMPORTANT: Be sure not to over-drive the fastener past the nail slot, this can lead to a condition known as a
>       telegraphing fastener. A telegraphing fastener is the visible effect of excessive pressure being placed on the
>       wood fibers which causes the appearance of a bump to occur just above the fasteners. This condition becomes
>       most apparent when natural or artificial light reflects across the surface of the floor causing the bump to
>       become visible to the eye. This condition can sometimes be difficult to see, so make sure to thoroughly
>       examine the first few rows of flooring to make certain telegraphing does not exist. Johnson Premium Hardwood
>       does not warrant against this condition since telegraphing fasteners are not manufacturing related. If you
>       should encounter this condition immediately stop the installation and contact Johnson’s Technical Department
>       and or the manufacturer of the nailer for technical advice. It is essential that the flooring installer make sure that
>       the nailer/stapler is properly adjusted for the particular floor that is being installed i.e. the fastener(s) MUST
>       enter the nail slot at the correct angle and height, do not over-drive the fastener(s) so as not to cause damage
>       to the board e.g. telegraphing fasteners, broken or split tongues, peaking, squeaking, or crackling noises to
>       occur.

I'm redoing it -- 3 day - $600 lesson learned. Read more carefully....